# Cannot Set Material to Metaballs

Tags: materials, meta-objects

I'm still fairly new to Blender and I have a question I cant seem to find the answer to. I'm trying to make this low-poly bonsai tree by creating leaves with Metaballs but I can't seem to set the material for the Metalball groups. [image]

As you can see, the material field is blank. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or I haven't turned on the proper settings. Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

scroll up on the properties window (see that bar on the far right?

[image]

Comment: xD I'm so Blind......

Answer (score 0):

Two quick issues, I can see here

1. You are using **Blender render**, please switch to **Cycles render**
2. your Properties window for the materials has been scroll down, please scroll up to see the option.

Comment: Metaballs work fine on Blender Render.

Comment: @cegaton : Agreed with you, just giving him both option, if he like :)

Comment: Using blender render is not an "issue".